# UITableView cell layout when cells are recycled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

So I have implemented a cell with various different heights. The issue is that sometimes when the cell is loaded the height that it has is incorrect and I'd have to basically scroll down until the cell is not visible and then scroll back up again, so it gets re-layouted and has the correct height. How do I fix this?

Comment: I haven't done exactly this but usually when re-used cells don't look right it's because a property is not being set correctly in cellForRowAtIndexPath: when the request for a cached cell comes back non-nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off giving some code would help.

1) If you only have a few set heights. Such as 3 different cell heights, then you can create 3 different cell identifiers so that the reused cells are the wrong height.

2) If you cells are dynamic heights then make sure when you are reusing a cell that you are setting its properties correctly. For example if you are setting the height property with in cell == nil. You are only setting it on creation of new cells.

```
if(cell == nil)
{
    // Create new cell
}

// Set cell height.
```

Also have you tried using

```
– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: This is correct, however if you do a lot of calculation in that method your table will load very slowly (it queries the height of all rows before displaying data)